# Cant get a JSON response from an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a login web page. I want to make an AJAX request to my API when the form is submitted, and the API returns the status code (login correct or not) in JSON.
From here, I could send the request, and I could see that the request was going on the API and the authentification was done (if I look at API). But the problem is that I can't get the response of the API from the web page, so I can't see, from the login page, if authentification was done or not.

Here's my code:

```
$("#login-form").submit(function(event){
  var email = $("#email").val();
  var password = $("#password").val();

  var query = {
    "email": email,
    "password": password
  };

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://192.168.0.24:6767/login',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(query),
    crossDomain: true,

    success: function(json_data){
      console.log(json_data);
    },

    error: function(XHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(errorThrown);
    }
  });
});
```

Here's the output on console developper (I'm on chrome):
[image]

My API is written in Rust and send back JSON data for sure. A Content-Type header has also have been set.

The weirdest thing is that sometimes, I get "error" on console. I really don't know what's happening with the login page and I would like some help. Thank you.

Comment: Try logging `xhr.responseText` in `console` and see what you get.. Also if possible post your API method..

Comment: You need to prevent the default action of submitting the form using `event.preventDefault` or similar

Comment: Could you please you be more clear ? Sorry I'm totally new in asynchronous world

Comment: `$("#login-form").submit(function(event){ event.preventDefault(); /* etc... */ });`

Comment: place a `return false` at the bottom of your submit function

Comment: I'll try this. Thank you !

Comment: also look into `.serialize()` rather than manually building the post data

Comment: Heeey, that's it ! I've got the json_data variable, but the browser is weird: when I click on submit button, there's no loading

Comment: Just another question, is this simple to make it like this ? I mean the status code sent back by the API can be intercepted, right ?

Comment: Personally I would never use Ajax to log in. In webforms I would use .net controls and in MVC I would use HttpPost controller method. Nothing is ever completely secure, Ajax is to raw/exposed for sensitive data.

Comment: HTTPS encrypts the communication thus adding an extra layer of security. I suppose it's me being "too" concerned. I hate the idea of being able to "view page source" find the method and understand the mechanics. Having said that if your security server side is "well" handled, then I guess it's fine.

Comment: Yes of course when I display all the mechanism, I be sure to secure it in the back :)
Thank you for your opinion.

Comment: @Jhun absolutely no problem, all the best.